# Android SDK: Java SE development Kit (JDK) not found

Tags: java, android

[image]

I have installed Java runtime 6 to C:\src\libraries\jre6.

I installed Java JDK to `C:\src\libraries\javasdk`

My `%PATH%` is set to:

When I run the Android SDK installer I get the error

> Java SE development Kit (JDK) not found

I'm at a loss as to what the Android SDK cannot really find. What is wrong?

Comment: As I understand it you didn't install java to the default location ... may be that is the problem?

Comment: Is your PATH really set to nothing? Or did you forget to show it? Mine is set to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77

Comment: What is the screenshot? It doesn't show an error, and you didn't write a description, it still says "enter image description here". Who do you think that message is for?